# Scale & replace in Dataframe

Tags: r, scale

I need to scale some columns out of my dataframe and I found a function which did it perfectly. So my question is how to replace the scaled columns in my dataframe? Is there a specific function for that or am I supposed to do it in a different way?

```
df <- raw_data %>%
  select(CLIENTNUM:Avg_Utilization_Ratio) %>%
  rename(Customer_Nr = CLIENTNUM,
         Customer_Act = Attrition_Flag,
         Total_Product_Count = Total_Relationship_Count)


scaled <- scale(select(df, Customer_Nr, Customer_Age, Dependent_count, Months_on_book,
                       Total_Product_Count, Months_Inactive_12_mon, Contacts_Count_12_mon, Credit_Limit,
                       Total_Revolving_Bal, Avg_Open_To_Buy, Total_Amt_Chng_Q4_Q1, Total_Trans_Amt,
                       Total_Trans_Ct)
                , center = T, scale = T)
```

Comment: `mutate(iris, across(starts_with("Sepal"), scale))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a character vector of column name and apply `scale` only on those columns.

```
cols <- c('Customer_Nr', 'Customer_Age', 'Dependent_count' .....)
df[cols] <- scale(df[cols])
```

Using an example of `mtcars` dataset :

```
df <- mtcars
cols <- c('mpg', 'disp')
df[cols] <- scale(df[cols])
df

#                        mpg cyl    disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4            0.1509   6 -0.5706 110 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag        0.1509   6 -0.5706 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710           0.4495   4 -0.9902  93 3.85 2.32 18.6  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive       0.2173   6  0.2201 110 3.08 3.21 19.4  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout   -0.2307   8  1.0431 175 3.15 3.44 17.0  0  0    3    2
#Valiant             -0.3303   6 -0.0462 105 2.76 3.46 20.2  1  0    3    1
#...
#...
```